# Preventing an NSManagedObject reference updating a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, reference

**Background info:**

We have an app which populates tableviews from Core Data. This app has a syncing mechanism implemented which updates the CoreData data in a background context and automatically merges back to the main context when it's done.

To keep the example simple, let's assume a `Message` and a `Comment` 'entity' where a Message can have zero or more Comments. We have subclassed `NSManagedObjects` for all our entities and therefore have a property called `comments` (which is of type `Set<Comment>`)  on our `Message` class.

A requirement of the app is that a view may **only** update the data on the screen when navigating to a new screen. This means that when you're on a screen and any data updates in the background, the visible data should remain the **same**.

Our `MessageViewcontroller` has a private property `message` which gets populated in `viewDidLoad`. Inside `cellForRowAt indexPath` we use `cell.message = message.comments[indexPath.row]`.

**Problem:**

The problem with this is that if we have updated a comment in our background context, which gets merged back to the main context, 'scrolling' up and down in the tableview (triggering the `cellForRowAt indexPath` again) will update the cell with the updated text.

This makes sense because our `message` property is a reference which represents the data in our CoreData.

**Question:**

How do I prevent the `message` variable from updating? Or put differently: how can I keep a 'snapshot' of a message object (and their relationships) when loading the view controller?

**Solution?**

The only solution I think could work is to create a struct with the same properties and populate that when loading the view. I don't really like this approach because our model is way more complicated than this `Message` example and has many relationships, recursion, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 9 you can use `queryGenerationTokens`.  A generation token is a pointer to a state that core-data was in at a particular time.  You create a new main queue managedObjectContext attached directly to the persistent store coordinator and set its `queryGenerationToken` to be the current one.  Also set `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to false.  Perform your fetches on this new context and you will not get any updates or changes from anything else that happens with core data.  When the user leaves the page you can discard the context, and when he goes back to the page you can create a new one.  Contexts are not resource intensive and you shouldn't be afraid of creating and discarding them as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've never heard of `queryGenerationTokens` before but it looks like this is exactly what I need. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: Looks like it's working perfectly. I now use `persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()` and pin it's generation by using `ctx.setQueryGenerationFrom(NSQueryGenerationToken.current)` whenever I need to update. Looks like I don't even need to set the `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` to false, or should I set it just to make sure? 

One important thing I noticed is that I need to call `ctx.refreshAllObjects()` ([source](https://cocoacasts.com/what-are-core-data-query-generations/)) after changing the generation in order to be able to see the changed data.

Comment: FYI: Documentation of `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` states that: "Setting this property to YES when the context is pinned to a non-current query generation is not supported."