# MVVM with CoreData query

Tags: ios, core-data, mvvm

First time I'm implementing *MVVM Architecture* with core data. I need to design *UITabviewcontroller* in on First tab I'm displaying user info on Second Tab I'm editing user info. For editing and displaying user I'm using core data model object *(NSManageObject)* with single manage object context. I'm binding user edited data with user *NSManageObject*.

Now the problem is during editing if I switch to display user tab all edited user info is showing. This I want to prevent till save button not pressed and user edited data not save on server should not reflect on display user tab the changes.

1. How to solve above problem ?
2. Is it good practise to use same model for core data and view (viewcontroller) presentation purpose? why ?
3. Should I use multiple manageobjectcontexts to solve above problem ?

Comment: You can continue with your approach of binding user edited data with ManagedObject but make sure you bind to managed object in different managed object context. So yes, you should be using multiple managedObjectContext to solve the problem. But using multiple managedObject will only solve the problem partially, from iOS 10 onwards you can make use of `queryGenerationTokens` to prevent the changes from propagating from parent managed object context or persistent store  :) Take a look at

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47923032/preventing-an-nsmanagedobject-reference-updating-a-uitableviewcell

Comment: thanks for quick response.

Comment: @SandeepBhandari is it good practise to use same model for core data and view (viewcontroller) presentation in mvvm

Comment: am a beginner with MVVM myself buddy so I don't think I'll be a good one to clearly help you out here but I can tell you what am doing, I am using the same model for core data and view model, am using FRP framework RxSwift so I bindy data in viewmodel to uicomponents in view controller